# If there is anyway I could use instead make everything as readkey? i only need to quit when i entered "q";

Tags: c#, syntax-error

If i use `readline()` i could not use `readkey();` to avoid read twice

```
Console.Write("Your selection is: ");
bSelAns = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iSelection);
string ans =iSelection.ToString();
```

i do `readline` here so i try to avoid `readkey();`

```
ConsoleKey keychar ;
keychar = ConsoleKey.Q;
string y = "q";
```

I need to bool exit when i enter q;

```
if (bSelAns ==false)
{
  if (ans == y)
  {
    break;
  }

  Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid strinng, please enter a number or string from the list.\n");
}
```

Comment: actually i used to make it all ReadKey() to make it simple, but I still wanna to see if I can have something new. I know I could not bool int and key inside If() so i tried string which do not work. Is there anyway i could edit so I do not need to delete  Console.Readline()?

Comment: if you want to only exit on 'q', then you need a loop. you can then have your exit condition check in that loop.

so that means every time it was not 'q', it will process the command, and reset into readkey again.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I think I misunderstood what you were looking for.
So I guess what you want is to be able to use ReadKey and Readline together?
that is impossible as ReadKey end after the first char, and readLine will end when Enter is pressed.. however, you could make ReadKey act as a ReadLine, and then you can check if Q is pressed for each keypress. 
to do that you need a buffer, that saves all keypresses, and each time 'Enter' is pressed, it empties the Buffer to the screen.

Edit: Logic for 'Enter' changed to reset if pressed, even if the buffer is empty

Edit2: Added Comments

```
using System;
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args){
        var buffer = "";
        while(true){
            //Only show if buffer is empty
            if(buffer.Length == 0){
            Console.WriteLine("enter key:");
            }
            var key = Console.ReadKey(false);

            //Only Exit if buffer is empty and Q is pressed (if Q is the first Key pressed)
            if(buffer.Length == 0 && key.Key == ConsoleKey.Q){
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("the key was 'Q' goodbye");
                return;
            }
            //Every time Enter is pressed, Use and Flush the buffer
            else if(key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                if(buffer.Length > 0){
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("buffer have {0}", buffer);
                    if(int.TryParse(buffer, out int number)){
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a number!", number);
                    }
                }
                buffer = "";
            }
            //else will capture everything else pressed, and add it to buffer
            else{
                buffer += key.KeyChar;
            }
        }
    }
}
```